# Strange refresh issue with Chromium on Gentoo

Tags: kde, gentoo, chrome

My system is Gentoo 64bit, with KDE4. I have installed chromium and have been using it for a long time without any problem. But recently, I noticed a strange issue. For example, in a text box, if I type *hello*, only *hell* will be displayed. The last *o* will be displayed only if I do something that could cause page update, like scroll up/down, hover my mouse over a link. This problem also happens with other input controls. I have tried to re-emerge the package, but it does not fix this problem. I really have no idea how to trouble this issue. There's no error log at all.

Comment: Did it happen after some system/portage update? You could try many things: 1) re-emerge video drivers, 2) emerge older video drivers or older chromium version, 3) run `emerge --update --newuse --deep --with-bdeps=y @world`, 4) run `revdep--rebuild`, 5) run `emerge @preserved-rebuild`, 6) enable/disable GPU acceleration in Chromium settings

Comment: I observe the same here with emacs. @roomcays: I have tried that - no effect.

Comment: Another issue might be fonts. I do not know exactly whot could help in this particular case, but I would give a try to: `eselect fontconfig disable 70-yes-bitmaps.conf` and `eselect fontconfig enable 70-no-bitmaps.conf`. Maybe some fonts are missing? Playing around with `eselect fontconfig` might result in some success...

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Synergy? I also had this problem (just the hover issue) and found that it was caused by that. Sopping synergy fixes this. I'll try updating it because I need it...

Comment: No I do not use Synergy. The symptom has gone recently. I think it is really a Chromium issue, and is resolved in recently version.